# Create multiple empty lists with different names

Tags: python, list

```
la = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I'd like to create three empty lists with names corresponding to items in the list:

```
la_A = []
la_B = []
la_C = []
```

I tried

```
(l_la[i]) = ([] for i in len(la))
```

But not work.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dictionary instead

```
la = {c: [] for c in la}
print(la['A'])
```

prints

```
[]
```